# Requesting an OAuth access token using a SAML assertion

Tags: c#, oauth, saml, bearer-token, federated-identity

I'm attempting to retrieve an OAuth access token using a SAML assertion. 
I need the access token to hit a resource API in the backend.

I'm currently posting a base64 url encoded SAML assertion.

curly braces indicated redacted values

```
      var result = string.Empty;
      var ClientId = {{Guid value}};
      var ApiResourceId = {{Guid value}};
      var authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{{tenantID}}";
      var assertionType = "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer";
      var encodedAssertion = Base64UrlEncoder.Encode(XMLAssertion);
      using (var client = new HttpClient())
      {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("client-request-id", ClientId);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("return-client-request-id", "true");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));
        var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        dict.Add("client_id", ClientId);
        dict.Add("grant_type", "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:saml2-bearer");
        dict.Add("assertion", encodedAssertion);
        dict.Add("scope", "{{scope value}}");

        var req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, string.Format("{0}/oauth2/v2.0/token", authority)) { Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(dict) };
        var res = client.SendAsync(req).Result;
        var task = res.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().ContinueWith(t =>
        {
          using (var reader = new StreamReader(t.Result))
            while (reader.Peek() > 0)
              result += reader.ReadLine();
        });
        task.Wait();
      }
```

I'm trying to get an access token I can use to request a bearer token to use the resource API. I need to use the SAML assertion to authenticate the user has logged in.

I'm currently getting this error back (again with the tenant id redacted)

```
{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"AADSTS50107: Requested federation realm object 
'https://sts.windows.net/{{tenantID}}/' does not exist. Trace 
ID: {{guid value1}} Correlation 
ID: {{guid value2}} Timestamp: 2019-01-28 02:33:48Z",
"error_codes":[50107],"timestamp":"2019-01-28 02:33:48Z","trace_id":"{{guid value1}}",
"correlation_id":"{{guid value2}}"}
```

Comment: I would conslut the documentation for the authentication system you are connecting to.  You wtrealm address is wrong.

Comment: This is the address returned in the assertion. The user has already successfully been authenticated, I'm trying to use that assertion (as proof the user was authenticated) to request an access token to use with the resource API.